# Solve the matrix equation $X ^ 3 = A$, with $X \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and given $A$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have to solve the matrix equation:

$$X^3 = A$$

where

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

So in the end I have to solve:

$$X^3 =  \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Since we have $2$ x $2$ matrices I tried the following:

$$X ^ 3 = A$$

$$\det(X^3) = \det(A)$$

$$\det(X)^3 = 3$$

$$\det(X) = \sqrt[3]{3}$$

I did this in hopes that it would result in the determinant of $X$ being $0$ so then I could've used the [Cayley-Hamilton identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem):

$$X^2 - tr(X) X + det(X) I_2 = O_2$$

where $tr(x) = (a + d)$ (trace of the matrix).

But since the determinant is not $0$, I can't abuse that, it looks complicated since that last term does not get canceled.

Then I tried to use the notation:

$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$

and to do the multiplication $X \cdot X \cdot X$ and then to equate it to $A$ and try to find $a, b, c, d$ but the algebra got very ugly very fast and I lost myself in the calculations.

So how should I approach this?

Comment: Note: your method is interesting for square roots https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cms_upload/Square_Roots-Sullivan13884.pdf, since it replaces $X^2$ with $A$, but this trick is not working for cube roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix $A$ has $2$ eigenvalues: $1$ and $3$. The vectors $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ are eigenvectors that correspond to the eigenvalues $1$ and $3$ respectively. Therefore, if$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$(the colums of $P$ are the eigenvectors), then$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}.$$So, take\begin{align}X&=P\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\sqrt[3]3\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\\&=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt[3]3+1&\sqrt[3]3-1\\\sqrt[3]3-1&\sqrt[3]3+1\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}

Comment: I have a question,Here Matrix $A$ is symmetric so matrix $P$ can be represented by eigen vectors of matrix $A$,but if matrix $A$ is not symmetric then how can we find $P$ ?

Comment: I did not use *at all* that $A$ is symmetric. The method that I have used works for any diagonalizable matrix (and it still works if it is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ but not over $\Bbb R$).

Comment: You'll have to excuse me but I'm a little rusty on my linear algebra so I have a question. I understand that you diagonalized $A$ and then equated $X^3$ to the product between the eigenvector matrix, eigenvalue matrix and inverse of eigenvector matrix. But we need $X$ and not $X^3$. So you took the third root of the eigenvalue matrix. But can we do that? I know that with a bit of algebra we can show $A^n=V \Lambda ^n V^{-1}$, but does that hold for $n<1$? I've never thought about that. If it does, is there some sort of explanation as to why?

Comment: \begin{align}X^3&=\left(P\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\sqrt[3]3\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\right)^3\\&=P\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\sqrt[3]3\end{bmatrix}^3P^{-1}\\&=P\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\\&=A.\end{align}

Comment: So then I can indeed use $A ^ n = V \Lambda ^ n V ^ {-1}$ even if $n < 1$? Whatever that $n$ smaller than $1$ might be?

Comment: I am sorry, but I fail to understand you references to $n<1$. All I did was to use the equality $\left(PAP^{-1}\right)^n=PA^nP^{1}$ when $n$ is a natural number. What made you think the I ever used an exponent smaller than $1$?

Answer (score 0):

The Cayley-Hamilton theorem provides a way to solve this without performing a full diagonalization: since the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is quadratic, then any function of $A$ that can be expressed as a power series in $A$ is equal to $aI+bA$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$. This also holds for eigenvalues of $A$. That is, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and we have $f(A)=aI+bA$, then $f(\lambda)=a+b\lambda$.

The eigenvalues of this matrix can be found by inspection to be $1$ and $3$, so the problem is reduced to solving the system $$a+b=1\\a+3b=\sqrt[3]3$$ and then assembling the matrix $aI+bA$.

As I mentioned, eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this particular matrix are easily found by inspection, so I’m not sure that this is really any less work than diagonalizing $A=PDP^{-1}$ and then computing $PD^{1/3}P^{-1}$, but I think there’s less opportunity for error since no matrix multiplications are involved.